# Selector for just the text of a div?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to have the cursor change when the user hovers over the text of my `div` rather than the `div` itself. I currently have :

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
}
div:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello
</div>
```

Is there a way for me to somehow select just the text of a `div` and apply a hover effect on just the text itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can't select text nodes in the CSS, you would have to wrap it in order to select it.

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
}
div span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

However, if you want a work-around, you could add the text via a pseudo element like this:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
}
div:after {
  content: 'Hello';
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Was hoping to not use <span> but I guess if that is all there is. Thanks

Comment: @Pipeline You can use same CSS posted in this answer and add the span via javascript

Comment: @Pipeline I just added an alternative work-around.. it's clearly not ideal, and it definitely won't work in all cases, but you could always use a pseudo element.

Comment: Thanks, can accept the answer is 6 minutes

Comment: How can I select the text in the span using JQuery?

Comment: @Pipeline If you want to select the text node and wrap it with a `span`, you could use `$('div').contents().wrap('<span></span>');`... that will work based on the markup you provided, although the `div` selector is too generic. You should add a class or id to the element in order to target it.. (but you probably already know that...).

Comment: @Pipeline you'll need a `.class-name` or an `#id` on that parent div so you can target it by that, otherwise it would be too generic

Comment: @Pipeline `$('div').wrapInner('<span></span>');` would work as well.

Comment: With regard to your `after` solution, the OP wants to change the cursor on hover; will your solution work that way?

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
}
div p {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the text into a 'p' tag then apply the hover to that instead

Comment: `p` tag adds padding, `span` suits this case much better

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Not really. HTML only defines the document structure instead of styling. Using unmeaningful tags such as `<span>` and `<div>` is discouraged unless it's necessary.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I agree about using `div` and `span` as last resort, but for the `p` tag >> "The HTML <p> element (or HTML Paragraph Element) represents a *paragraph* of text.  *Paragraphs* are usually represented in visual media by *blocks of text *that are *separated* from adjacent blocks by *vertical blank space or first-line indention*."

Comment: While the `span` >> "The HTML <span> element is a *generic inline container* for phrasing content, which does not inherently represent anything. It can be used to group elements *for styling purposes* (using the class or id attributes)"

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Yes, the docs is saying that the `<p>` tag should be used for paragraph purposes that are expected to be separated from adjacent blocks. However it does not specify that it will add any padding (you can undo any padding added by the user agent anyway.)

Comment: Sure you can, as you can eliminate `ul` padding, but `p` is for *blocks of text* and it is a *block* element, while `span` is *inline* and could be used for styling purposes , also kindly look at the example here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span which used span for styling only